# Error en mi consulta para obtener un valor y sumar

Tags: php, mysql, prestashop, prestashop1.7

Estoy trabajando en un módulo de *Prestashop* donde necesito ejecutar una consulta a una tabla para obtener un valor y sumarlo, el problema es que me esta arrojando un error, es primera vez que trabajo un módulo de *Prestashop* y quede algo perdido.

Este es mi código y aquí es donde tengo el error:

```
$result = Db::getInstance(_PS_USE_SQL_SLAVE_)->executeS("SELECT `value` FROM `" . _DB_PREFIX_ . "feature_product`  
            INNER JOIN  `" . _DB_PREFIX_ . "feature_value_lang` ON `" . _DB_PREFIX_ . "feature_product.id_feature_value` = `" . _DB_PREFIX_ . "feature_value_lang.id_feature_value` 
            WHERE `" . _DB_PREFIX_ . "feature_product.id_feature` = 762");
```

y lo tengo dentro de esta funcion

```
private function calcularNumBultos($order)
    {
        $numBultos = 0;
        $products = $order->getProducts();
        
        foreach($products as $key => $product)
        {
            $result = Db::getInstance(_PS_USE_SQL_SLAVE_)->executeS("SELECT `value` FROM `" . _DB_PREFIX_ . "feature_product`  
            INNER JOIN  `" . _DB_PREFIX_ . "feature_value_lang` ON `" . _DB_PREFIX_ . "feature_product.id_feature_value` = `" . _DB_PREFIX_ . "feature_value_lang.id_feature_value` 
            WHERE `" . _DB_PREFIX_ . "feature_product.id_feature` = 762");

            $numBultos += array_sum($result);
            dd($numBultos);

        }
        //die($numBultos);
        return $numBultos;
    }
```

Esta función la llamo dentro del proceso del carro de compras en el cual busco obtener unos valores dentro de las características del producto y sumarlas

El error que me arroja es este:

`Unknown column 'ps_feature_product.id_feature_value' in 'on clause'`

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Lo que te dice es que la tabla `ps_feature_product` no tiene una columna llamada `id_feature_value`, ¿es posible que esté mal escrita el nombre de la columna?

Comment: si la tiene amigo, esta bien escrito tambien el nombre...

Comment: El error está claro. Revisa si existe la tabla y la columna o la conexión a la base de datos correcta. Poco más podemos aportar con esos datos.

Comment: la tabla existe amigo, de todas formas dejo captura en actualizacion del post

Comment: La columna es `id_product` y estás usando `id_product_value`, solo elimina `_value` y ya debe funcionar.

Comment: es una sola base de datos???

Answer (score 1):

Prueba cambiando las comillas dobles por las simples y quitando las comillas invertidas salvo a *value*, para que coja el nombre del campo que le quieres asignar en lugar del VALUE de SQL. Si te da igual el nombre del campo, deja el valor predeterminado quitando *AS `value`*, pero teniendo en cuenta que no tiene ningún campo llamado *value* es *id_feature_value*. También he dejado la sentencia en una variable, porque me gusta hacerlo así, pero puedes obviarlo.

```
private function calcularNumBultos($order)
{
    $numBultos = 0;
    $products = $order->getProducts();
    $sql = 'SELECT fp.id_feature_value AS `value` FROM ' . _DB_PREFIX_ . 'feature_product fp  
        INNER JOIN  ' . _DB_PREFIX_ . 'feature_value_lang fvl ON fvl.id_feature_value = fp.id_feature_value 
        WHERE fp.id_feature = 762';
    
    foreach($products as $key => $product)
    {
        $result = Db::getInstance(_PS_USE_SQL_SLAVE_)->executeS($sql);

        $numBultos += array_sum($result);
        dd($numBultos);

    }
    //die($numBultos);
    return $numBultos;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

El código de arriba queda más bonito. Sin embargo, el problema viene de estar poniendo la comilla invertida también a la tabla, debe ser solo para el campo, quedando así.

```
$result = Db::getInstance(_PS_USE_SQL_SLAVE_)->executeS("SELECT `value` FROM " . _DB_PREFIX_ . "feature_product  
        INNER JOIN " . _DB_PREFIX_ . "feature_value_lang ON " . _DB_PREFIX_ . "feature_product.`id_feature_value` = " . _DB_PREFIX_ . "feature_value_lang.`id_feature_value` 
        WHERE " . _DB_PREFIX_ . "feature_product.`id_feature` = 762");
```

Otra opción es hacerlo para la tabla por un lado y el campo por otro, pero nunca juntos. Quedaría así:

```
$result = Db::getInstance(_PS_USE_SQL_SLAVE_)->executeS("SELECT `value` FROM `" . _DB_PREFIX_ . "feature_product`  
        INNER JOIN `" . _DB_PREFIX_ . "feature_value_lang` ON `" . _DB_PREFIX_ . "feature_product`.`id_feature_value` = `" . _DB_PREFIX_ . "feature_value_lang`.`id_feature_value` 
        WHERE `" . _DB_PREFIX_ . "feature_product`.`id_feature` = 762");
```

Eso contando con que tengas `value` en esa tabla, que por defecto no viene, si no sería `id_feature_value`

Un saludo.

Comment: Efectivamente, el problema es que agrupa tabla y campo dentro de ``. Por lo demás, quería aclarar que el campo `value` sí está. Es de la tabla `feature_value_lang`.